# Hide font range without text on next page moving up a page

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I am currently working on generating a Word document which will hide parts of a document, depending on the type of insurance selected.

```
if (g.First().GetProductCategory() == "Income Protection")
        {
          this.document.Bookmarks.get_Item("life_insurance").Range.Font.Hidden = 1;
          this.document.Bookmarks.get_Item("tpd").Range.Font.Hidden = 1;
        }
        else
        {
          this.document.Bookmarks.get_Item("income_protection").Range.Font.Hidden = 1;
        }
```

This works well, but I have a small problem - Portions from the next page move up, and affect the formatting of the document. I am trying to better understand Word Interop to be able to address this problem.

How does one hide ranges without having stuff from the next page move up? Looking forward to all assistance here. Thanks everyone. :)

Comment: can you use Page Breaks effectively?

Comment: Yeah... I actually did that. I was thinking of a programmatic way without realising that I could have just done this. Silly me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Page Breaks for each section.